# Prove that the Markov chain is reversible if and only if there exist a diagonal matrix D and a symmetric matrix A such that P = AD.

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I need some help with the proof as I am not sure if it is right.

**Edit**

After reading Botnakov N. comment, I gave the proof another shot.

Since the Markov chain is irreducible then there exists a unique stationary distribution. Assuming that the markov chain is reversible then the detailed balance equations hold:

$$\pi(i) p_{i j}=\pi(j) p_{j i}, \quad i, j \in S$$

Let D = [ $\pi(1)$, ...... , $\pi(n)$] and using the fact that P = AD, then:

$$ p_{ji} = {[AD]}_{ji} = a_{ji} * \pi(j)$$

I know that $a_{ji} = \frac{\pi(i)}{\pi(j)} * a_{ij}$ from the detailed balance equations. Hence:

$$ p_{ji} = a_{ji} * \pi(j) = \frac{\pi(i)}{\pi(j)} * a_{ij}  * \pi(j) = \pi(i) * a_{ij} = p_{ij} $$

Thus, P is a symmetric matrix. But I am not sure how to conclude it.

Now, I assume that there exists a symmetric matrix P such that for all i,j in S, $p_{i j}= p_{j i}$ then the komologrov loop criterion is satisfied then the chain is reversible.

*I am not sure how to show this in detailed*

Answer (score 2):

You write: "This implies that for all $n,\left(X_{0}, X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)$ has the same distribution as $\left(X_{n}, X_{n-1}, \ldots, X_{0}\right)$. therefore, $p_{i j}= p_{j i}$ and hence P is a symmetric matrix." No, $p_{ij} \ne p_{ji}$. It's not a corollary and moreover it's false. For example, consider a chain with transition matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
\frac12 & \frac12 \\
\frac13 & \frac23 \end{pmatrix}
Here $p_{12} \ne p_{21}$ and an easy computation gives that $\pi_1 = \frac25, \pi_2 = \frac35$ for probabilities of stationary distribution. Hence $\pi_1 p_{12} = \pi_2 p_{21}$ and the chain is reversible, q.e.d.

**Remark** In case when there are only $2$ states every chain with stationary distribution is reversible, because $\pi_1 p_{11} + \pi_2 p_{21} = \pi_1$ (as $\vec{\pi}$ is stationary) and it follows that $$\pi_1 p_{12} = \pi_1 (1-p_{11}) = \pi_1 -  \pi_1 p_{11} = (\pi_1 p_{11} + \pi_2 p_{21}) - \pi_1 p_{11} = \pi_2 p_{22}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realised the assumption I made and it was wrong so I gave the proof another go.